# How to remove all associated files and configuration settings of an app installed through 'force architecture' command

Tags: package-management

A few weeks ago I installed a 32 bit `.deb` file through the 'force architecture' command (on my 64bit notebook), however the procedure was unsuccessful and I used the `apt-get purge`command to uninstall the app. It seems there are some leftovers of the app I uninstalled which has now broken system update. Synaptic recommended a `sudo apt-get install -f`which I did in the terminal with this initial response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libntfs10
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  crossplatformui
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

I chose 'Y' then got this response:

```
(Reading database ... 187616 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing crossplatformui ...
ztemtvcdromd: no process found
dpkg: error processing crossplatformui (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossplatformui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems the app I installed `crossplatformui`is still on my system and has caused update manager to stop running with a partial upgrade warning. What do I do now?

Comment: now I can't install anything as Software center and terminal both report that the package 'crossplatformui' needs to be uninstalled first Please help

Comment: There is a similar question on launchpad located:https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/122715 Can you see if step #6 helps if your comfortable with trying it.

Comment: Seems he had to reinstall Ubuntu as he wasn't able to solve the issue

Comment: Had you tried remove it? sudo apt-get remove crossplatformui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had same problem as you had.
So what I did:

1- Go to Synaptic Package Manager and Remove [CrossPlatformUI] and all it's dependencies.
+ May be there still some package will be remain. No problem.

2- As is mentioned above, Run:

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

in terminal.

3- Search in the search area [Package: crossplatformui]
You will find four or five line address. I forgot those lines and I can not find them because they are removed. But, any way; follow every line address to find those files.

4- When you find exact files, Right Click on that and choose open as administrator. When file is open, Remove the content of those and save it.

5- Do it for all files. Now go back to Synaptic Package Manager, and mark those package which are remain as completely remove. Synaptic Package Manager will remove those.

6- finally go to terminal again and run again:

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

7- Search for [Package: crossplatformui] again and delete all the informations.

8- You are done. 
You can check in terminal by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove CrossPlatformUI
```

9- As soon as you connect to Internet, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you were right, there must be no error.

I hope this can help you, and sorry if I have forgot something. I am new to Linux. 
Good luck.

Comment: Is it necessary to do steps 3,4,5? Can we not directly remove the content from section from the status file?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe we can bypass dpkg like this.
First backup your original file:

`sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.orig`

After that open it to edit:

`gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Search for a block something like that:

> Package: crossplatformui
>
> ..
>
> ..
>
> Package: another_package_name

Here, you will delete only crossplatformui block. This means starting with **Package: crossplatformui** and till the other package block. After deleting the blocak try to remove it again:

`sudo dpkg -r crossplatformui`

Answer (score 0):

Well the only solution here is a complete re-install. Forcing that package to install messed up the system files beyond recovery

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `dpkg -P crossplatformui:architecture` ?