# Fixing dpkg after installation of broken packages?

Tags: apt, 12.04, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove all associated files and configuration settings of an app installed through 'force architecture' command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84723/how-to-remove-all-associated-files-and-configuration-settings-of-an-app-installe)

I installed a broken package, and now `apt-get`/`aptitude` is failing with trying to remove it
Each time I run a `apt` operation, this is the message I get:

```
Removing crossplatformui ...
ztemtvcdromd: no process found
dpkg: error processing crossplatformui (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossplatformui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

running `sudo apt-get install -f` gives me this:

```
amith@amith-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  crossplatformui
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1123 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 340804 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing crossplatformui ...
ztemtvcdromd: no process found
dpkg: error processing crossplatformui (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossplatformui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Similar question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/84723/how-to-remove-all-associated-files-and-configuration-settings-of-an-app-installe